# Почему при взломе константной переменной я не получаю ошибку?

Tags: c++, отладка, const

Если я создам переменную `const int i = 0;`, а затем изменить ее через `i=1;`, то я получу ошибку. Однако если я скомпилирую программу в exe, и изменю это константное значение через cheat engine или другой отладчик, то я не получу никакой ошибки. Почему так?

Comment: Потому что все подобные проверки существуют только во время компиляции

Comment: @andreymal Защита памяти от записи в рантайме тоже бывает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat но не в таком виде и вряд ли неотключаемая

Comment: @andreymal Наверняка отключаемая. "В таком виде" - это в каком?

Comment: @DimoNull Это вы нам скажите, почему вы ожидали ошибку в cheat engine? `const` и защита памяти от записи - это разные вещи. `const` учитывается во время компиляции, и стандарт четко описывает его поведение. А такая защита - во время выполнения, и ее стандарт не описывает; она зависит от ОС, настроек компилятора, и черт знает чего, а может быть cheat engine умеет ее отключать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/const-cpp?view=msvc-160#:%7E:text=const%20%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE.):

> Ключевое `const`слово указывает, что значение переменной является
> константой, и указывает компилятору запретить программисту изменить
> его.

Т.е. другими словами, использование переменной с  ключевым словом `const` запрещает изменять данную переменную на уровне **компиляции** программы.

В результате работы для данной переменной выдается место в памяти. Если всю память приложения просканировать, затем отыскать данную переменную, а затем изменить значение по адресу в этой памяти, то переменная измениться (что собственно и делает `Cheat Engine`).

Стоит вопрос, а как можно защитить переменные от переписывания?

1. Можно создать методы проверки целостности данных, проверяя те же
   константы от других констант
2. [Обфускация кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), чтобы затрдунить поиск переменных в памяти в рантайме
3. Мониторинг внешних программ - выявляйте процесс `Cheat engine` и блокируйте работу программы (самый плохой метод, так как каждый может написать собственный софт для изменения переменных в памяти подобное `Cheat engine`)

Это малая часть того, что Я могу предложить. На самом деле методов защиты памяти существует много, это достаточно глубокая тема и совершенно другой вопрос, надеюсь это даст вам наводку на следующие действия...